# Bamboo headless protractor scripts failing , but passed in local

Tags: javascript, protractor, continuous-integration, bamboo

13:27:00] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
25-May-2018 13:27:00    [13:27:00] I/hosted - Using the selenium server at http://localhost:4444/wd/hub
25-May-2018 13:27:20    [13:27:20] E/launcher - Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
25-May-2018 13:27:20    Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
25-May-2018 13:27:20    System info: host: 'enl8-jdtagt-03v.adm.aamc.org', ip: '10.54.6.175', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
25-May-2018 13:27:20    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
25-May-2018 13:27:20    [13:27:20] E/launcher - WebDriverError: Timed out waiting for driver server to start.
25-May-2018 13:27:20    Build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: '7c6e0b3', time: '2018-05-08T15:15:08.936Z'
25-May-2018 13:27:20    System info: host: 'enl8-jdtagt-03v.adm.aamc.org', ip: '10.54.6.175', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '2.6.32-696.23.1.el6.x86_64', java.version: '1.8.0_45'
25-May-2018 13:27:20    Driver info: driver.version: unknown
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:546:15)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at parseHttpResponse (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at doSend.then.response (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:441:30)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
25-May-2018 13:27:20    From: Task: WebDriver.createSession()
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at Function.createSession (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:769:24)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at Function.createSession (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:761:15)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at createDriver (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:170:33)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at Builder.build (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/index.js:626:16)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at Hosted.getNewDriver (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/built/driverProviders/driverProvider.js:53:33)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at Runner.createBrowser (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:195:43)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at q.then.then (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/protractor/built/runner.js:339:29)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at _fulfilled (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/q/q.js:834:54)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at self.promiseDispatch.done (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/q/q.js:863:30)
25-May-2018 13:27:20        at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/opt/atlassian-bamboo/bamboo-agent-home/xml-data/build-dir/AQ-SMOK-JOB1/node_modules/q/q.js:796:13)
25-May-2018 13:27:20    [13:27:20] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 199
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR! errno 199
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR! WebAppUIautomation@0.1.0 HL: `protractor e2eFtHl.js --params.appEnv ftest --params.domain https://apps.ftest.aamc.org`
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR! Exit status 199
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR!
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR! Failed at the WebAppUIautomation@0.1.0 HL script.
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
25-May-2018 13:27:20
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
25-May-2018 13:27:20    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-05-25T17_27_20_792Z-debug.log
25-May-2018 13:27:20    Failing task since return code of [/usr/bin/node /usr/bin/npm run HL] was 199 while expected 0
25-May-2018 13:27:20    Finished task 'Run Headless Script' with result: Failed

Comment: exports.config = {

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
      capabilities: {
        'browserName': 'chrome',
        acceptInsecureCerts: true,
        chromeOptions: {
          args: [
              '--headless', 
              '--disable-gpu', 
              '--no-sandbox', 
              '--window-size=1920x1200',
              '--disable-web-security',
              '--allow-insecure-localhost'
               ]
        },
    
      } This is my configuration

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add steps to reproduce. Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"AS": "webdriver-manager update && webdriver-manager start --detach  --seleniumPort=8080 && protractor config.js --suite aADR  --params.appEnv uat --params.experienceId xxxx --params.domain xxx.xxx.com --params.state xx",

Answer (score 0):

First you have to start the server with this command:

```
webdriver-manager start
```